# Error Shown:Code coverage failure in production org even though my code coverage is 99% in the sandbox org

Tags: deployment

Hii I am deploying two classes along with their test class from the sandbox to the production org.

In my sandbox the code coverage are 99% and 94% respectively

[image: 99%]     [image]

But while I am validating it in the Production org I am getting the following as error message:
[image]

Though my code coverage is showing 99% and 94% in my production org.What can be the reason for this?Please guide me

Comment: make sure you don't have `seeAlldata  = true` in test classes.

Comment: Hi @TusharSharma I have already set seeAlldata = False .But still it is showing this error

Comment: have you added your test classes in the changeset? Otherwise, I don't see any other issue apart from it. What you can try, use "Run Specific Tests" option while deploying and enter your Test classes name in the box provided, each on next line. Please make sure that you include test classes in changeset.

Comment: Hii @NitishSinghal I made a mistake previously I didn't add the test class to  the Run Specified Tests option and I was just validating it without adding it in the option.now it is working fine and I was ableto deploy both the classes.This was the first time I have done deployment .So made a mistake while validating.Sorry for that

Comment: great.. please upvote and mark the answer to help the community. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you added your test classes in the changeset? Otherwise, I don't see any other issue apart from it. What you can try, use "Run Specific Tests" option while deploying and enter your Test classes name in the box provided, each on next line. Please make sure that you include test classes in changeset.